# How to call notifydatasetchanged when using SherlockFragmentActivity and ListFragments

Tags: android, tabs, android-listview, actionbarsherlock

I have a Sherlock Tab Navigation implemented as the following two classes.  Class `Dashboard` is the main activity.  Class `DashboardContacts` represents one of the tab's fragment.

I am loading HTTP data that gets loaded in a while and when it loads I need the list view in `DashboardContacts` to reflect the changes brought in from Server and refresh the `ListView` from blank to filled list.  For this i'm calling `notifyDataSetChanged` method through refresh method in `DashboardContacts`, but no change relects in `ListView` until I change the tabs.

```
public class Dashboard extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    private DashboardContacts contactsTab=new DashboardContacts();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);

        getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        ActionBar.Tab tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
        tab.setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dashboardTabs)[0]);
        tab.setTabListener(new DashboardHome());
        getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab);

        ActionBar.Tab tab2 = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
        tab2.setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dashboardTabs)[1]);
        tab2.setTabListener(contactsTab);
        getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab2);

        //CALLS ASYNCLOADER HERE TO LOAD HTTP DATA
    }

    private void httpSuccessMethod() {
        //Does some work and then calls:
        contactsTab.refresh(datasource.getAllContacts());

    }
```

Here is the DashboardContacts class layout:

```
public class DashboardContacts extends SherlockListFragment  implements ActionBar.TabListener{

    private UserListAdapter listAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        listAdapter=new UserListAdapter(container.getContext(), ApplicationState.getInstance(container.getContext()).getUserCache());
        setListAdapter(listAdapter);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart(); 
    }


    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab,android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.replace(android.R.id.content, this,"contacts");
        ft.attach(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab,android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.detach(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab,android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


        public void refresh(List<User> list) {
        if(this.listAdapter != null) {
        this.listAdapter.setList(list);
        this.listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

The refresh method in the custom list adapter looks like, so I am actually changing the data there too:

```
public void refresh(List<User> list) {
    if(this.listAdapter != null) {
        this.listAdapter.setList(list);
        this.listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Does your adapter see the new items?

Comment: hey @Luksprog, thanks for the reply.  TO answer your question, I think it does.  I did a little modifications and I just added a third snippet in my question body.  This is the refresh method which is now also being passed the dataset and then the `notifyDataSetMethod` called.  I do not see any change/improvement

Comment: thanks @Luksprog solved by leading towards where you pointed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is something I didn't implement, so I did it now and solved the issue:

```
public void setList(List<ExpensePool> list) {
    clear();
    addAll(list);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```